# display events on angular full calendar

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

i'm using angular full calendar with angular typescript 12 , i want to display some events but it's not working with what 'im doing
here is my code :

in HTML component

```
   <full-calendar  [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
```

in the typescript file :

```
  calendarOptions!: CalendarOptions;

ngOnInit(): void
  {


    this.calendarOptions = {

      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      
  
      events:
      [
        { title: 'event 1', start: '2020-08-01' , end:'2020-09-08'},
        { title: 'event 2', date: '2020-08-31' }
      ]
    };
  
  }
```

Comment: Based on your code, it works. Did you try to change the event date to the year 2021? Otherwise, you need to specify your question & issue in detail. Or create a Minimal, Reproducible Example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Comment: it worked after installing this package via :  npm i @fullcalendar/interaction

Comment: The interaction plugin is about interacting with events, it does not affect displaying them. I suspect that was actually a symptom of a different problem.